# How to read txt file interpreting the \n?

Tags: php

how to read a .txt file showing the html tag and interpreting the `\n` in the file.

I'm using a script php to read those files:

```
echo readfile("file.txt");
```

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `nl2br` function.

```
echo nl2br(readfile("file.txt"));
```

Comment: thanks i'll try it just for now.

Comment: the "\n" is not writen by hard in the file , it's interpreted in the file by a line break?